# codeigniter create array of checked checkboxes

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, checkbox

I have php form which has numerous check boxes. I need to store all the selected check boxes in an array and then use them from my controller. So far, in my controller I have

```
$data['categories']= array($this->input->post('category'))
```

where my check boxes are called "category". however this method is only storing a single check box value, even when numerous check boxes are selected.

I then intend to pass this array to a model for processing.

Thank you for the help, I appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view

```
<td><input type="text" name="category[]"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="category[]"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="category[]"/></td>
```

Notice, we added two brackets, to indicate that this is an array.

Then in your Controller you can loop through it or whatever you like.

```
foreach ( $this->input->post('category') as $category)
{
// some stuff here
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly, the full array is being passed!

Answer (score 1):

In your view, use `category[]` as a name for checkboxes.

Example:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="category[]" checked> Option 1
<input type="checkbox" name="category[]" checked> Option 2
etc...
```